# System.Net.WebException The remote server returned an error: NotFound with POST JSON request in Windows Phone 7

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

this might be a simple one.

I'm trying to make a simple POST request to something a friend of mine made, and a REST tester confirms that it is indeed working. This is my code:

```
private void sendJsonRequest()
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://boom.antomontani.com/api/v1/users.json");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback, httpWebRequest);
    }

    private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) asyncResult.AsyncState;

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);

        string json = "{ \"phone\": \"" + phone + "\" }";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, json.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
    }

    private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) asyncResult.AsyncState;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);

        string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        streamResponse.Close();
        reader.Close();

        response.Close();

        result = responseString;
    }
```

When debugging, the execution break at the EndGetResponse, with the exception

```
[System.Net.WebException]   {"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."}  System.Net.WebException
     at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at JSONBoom.PhoneNumber.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)\r\n   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()\r\n"
```

As far as I'm concerned, my WMAppManifest has ID_CAP_NETWORKING, which I read could be a possible cause for problems. Other than that, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: If run app on emulator. please check emulator is connect with internet or not just hit a url(www.google.com) from your emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The remote server returned an error: NotFound` on the phone means *any* failed HTTP status code in the response. You can view it in the debugger.

In your case, the server sends you HTTP status 400 "Bad Request". The reason is simple, you're setting incorrect ContentType. `text/json` [should be replaced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) with `application/json`.